# Tipagem do retorno no PHP 7. Quais as vantagens?

Tags: php, tipagem, php-7

Eu estava dando uma testada no PHP 7 e verifiquei que o mesmo agora aceita definir qual tipo de dado vai ser retornado.

Aqui vão alguns testes:

Definindo a instância que deve ser retornada

```
function test_object(): stdClass {

    return new ArrayObject;
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of test_object() must be an instance of stdClass, instance of ArrayObject returned

Definindo que o retorno deve ser do tipo float

```
function test_type(): float
{
    return 1; // Nesse caso, retorna float(1)
}

function test_type(): int
{
    return 1;// Nesse caso retorna int(1)
}

function test_type(): string
{
    return 1 + 1; // Nesse caso retorna string(2)
}

function test_type(): string {

    return array(1, 2, 3); // Fatal error
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of test_type() must be of the type string, array returned

Algumas pessoas podem até ter pontos de vista positivos em relação a isso, porém eu não posso dar opniões, pois venho do PHP 5 e desconheço essas práticas.

Quais são as vantagens da utilização da definição de tipo de retorno (tipagem de retorno)?

Como isso vai ajudar o desenvolvedor PHP?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A vantagem é justamente a que você viu e demonstrou na pergunta. O compilador tem condição de verificar se o tipo do dado usado no retorno corresponde ao que foi especificado pela função/método, gerando um erro logo no local onde ele foi causado e não propagado para outros locais do código onde fica mais difícil descobrir (se a linguagem fosse totalmente compilada seria melhor ainda).

É importante descobrir o erro o mais cedo e próximo possível de onde ele efetivamente ocorreu. Quando ele explode longe da causa fica muito mais difícil achá-lo.

Sem isto o erro só será percebido quando for usar o dado errado.

Obviamente se todo o código for escrito desta forma poderá evitar o uso da função em locais onde se espera outro tipo.

Claro que também ajuda documentar melhor a intenção. Inclusive ajuda se alguém fizer uma manutenção e mudar ou criar um caminho alternativo de execução que gere um retorno de tipo diferente do esperado. Antes isto poderia passar desapercebido.

É uma pena que é opcional, então PHP ainda é uma linguagem que o programador precisa se preocupar com o retorno na maior parte dos casos (isso melhorou um pouco em versões mais novas). Em outros ele nunca precisou se preocupar de fato porque a documentação já garantia que retornaria só um tipo.

O ganho ainda não é nem de perto o que poderia ser se tudo fosse tipado, mas é um ganho.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Gostei do _outros locais do código onde fica mais difícil descobrir_.

Comment: É, estourar em outro lugar é uma das coisas que mais deixa os programadores loucos.

Comment: Tinha um colega meu que procurou em todo o sistema uma variável que ele nunca achava. Ficou uma semana procurando. Depois ele entrou em contato com o programador e descobriu que ele tinha usado a _variável variável_. `$$pog = 'pog'`

Answer (score 15):

### Quais são as vantagens da utilização da definição de tipo de retorno (tipagem de retorno)?

As mesmas de qualquer linguagem com disciplina de tipos: a segurança e coesão e dados.

Em linguagens com tipagens dinâmicas, dependendo do que é retornado, é preciso verificar se o retorno está dentro do esperado, porque pode ser algo completamente imprevisto, dependendo da forma com que o sistema é feito.

### Como isso vai ajudar o desenvolvedor PHP?

Vai ajudar a evitar retornos indesejados e imprevistos de funções. O PHP deixa de ser uma linguagem cuja função retorna "qualquer coisa" para retornar algo definido, o que garante uma conveniência ao programador, que não precisa se preocupar com a verificação da estrutura de dados retornada.

Comment: Se o programador usar a tipagem de retorno, kkkkkkk. +1

Answer (score 11):

A vantagem de tipar o retorno do método, significa que o prometido será cumprido ou seu dinheiro de volta em forma de erro ou exception.

Atualmente no PHP5, o que pode acontecer é passar um tipo diferente do esperado e esperar a falha acontecer. O que evita isso um pouco é inferência de tipos nas declarações e métodos/funções.

Answer (score 0):

Tipagem vai além da garantia do tipo do retorno e boa praticas de programação. Acredito que o principal razão seja a utilização consciente de recurso de memoria.
O programador de PHP não entende a diferença na alocação de memória de uma variável do tipo String para uma do tipo inteiro e por esse motivo ele julga desnecessário.
Maquinas tem recursos limitados então é muito importante saber qual o tipo de variável é mais adequada em determinada rotina, pois isso influencia e muito na performance do sistema.

Comment: O que é melhor para economizar memória em PHP? Um array de ints, ou uma string? (considerando a mesma informação, só que armazenada das 2 maneiras)