# Retorno de função vazio

Tags: php, return, php-7, funções

Alguém poderia me dizer porque a minha função insert2 está retornando nulo após a inserção? ela deveria estar retornando a string com a mensagem de sucesso.

```
<?php
require_once 'conexao.php';
$con = new Conexao();

function insert($dados, $tabela, $campo_unico) : string{

    global $con;

    //Verifica se tem algum campo que tenha que ser único no BD
    if(is_null($campo_unico)) { 
        insert2($dados, $tabela);
    }else{ //Caso tenha verifica se já existe algum registro
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabela." WHERE ".$campo_unico."=:".$campo_unico;
        $select = $con->conectar()->prepare($sql);

        if(is_numeric($dados[$campo_unico])){
            $select->bindValue(":".$campo_unico, $dados[$campo_unico], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }else {
             $select->bindValue(":".$campo_unico, $dados[$campo_unico], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $select->execute();

        if( ($select->rowCount()) > 0) {
            return "O ".$campo_unico." informado já existe em nossos registros";
        }else {
            insert2($dados, $tabela);
        }

    }

}

function insert2($dados, $tabela) : string{
        global $con;

        $i = 0;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tabela . " (";
        foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
             if ($i == count($dados)-1) {
                $sql .= " ".$key." ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " ".$key.", ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql .= ")";
        $sql .= " values (";

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
             if ($i == count($dados)-1) {
                $sql .= " :".$key." ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " :".$key.", ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql .= ")";

        $insert = $con->conectar()->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($dados as $key => $valor) {
            if (is_numeric($valor)) {
                $insert->bindValue(":$key", $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            } else {
                $insert->bindValue(":$key", $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }
        if ($insert->execute()) {
            return "Registro inserido com sucesso";
        } else {
            return $insert->errorInfo();
        }
}
```

O error que está dando é este:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of insert() must be of the type string, none returned in ...:34

Que é justamente porque o retorno da função está sendo nulo
Stack trace:

Comment: É mais fácil você debugar esse código pra achar a causa do erro (linha e mensagem). Para operação tipo CRUD eu não recomendo você ter `return` com mensagem de sucesso ou erro; Você não vai saber o que é o que. Retorne uma flag bool ou o ultimo ID quando for insert e em caso de erro use as `exceptions` adequadamente.

Comment: Nunca vi isso, usar `:` no fim de uma função, sabe me indicar um link onde posso ter mais detalhes disso ?

Comment: @LeandroLima no php7 você pode especificar o tipo de retorno da função.

Comment: Papa o error que está tendo é este: Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of insert() must be of the type string, none returned in ... que é justamente porque está retornando vazio. Leandro Lima, essas são novas funcionalidades do php 7 que te permite escolher o tipo de retorno da função, da uma olhada ai : https://tableless.com.br/10-novidades-do-php-7/

Comment: @rray eu também não sabia, nesse caso daria erro se a função jogasse um `exception`?

Comment: vc chama sempre `insert()`? veja que nessa função tem uma chamada de `insert2($dados, $tabela);` e vc não pega o resultado.

Comment: Troque `insert2($dados, $tabela)` por: `return insert2($dados, $tabela)`

Comment: @guilermenascimento acho que isso só se aplica ao php7 (para frente) me parece importante manter a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em linguagens tipadas é bem comum especificar o tipo de retorno de um método e ele deve obedecer essa especificação do contrario o compilador emite um erro. No PHP7 funciona da mesma forma ou quase.

Veja que em `insert()` existe apenas uma return, deveria existir pelo menos dois. Deixei apenas o esqueleto da função para evidenciar o problema.

```
function insert($dados, $tabela, $campo_unico) : string{ //obriga a função retorna o tipo
    global $con;
    if(is_null($campo_unico)) {

    }else{ //Caso tenha verifica se já existe algum registro
        if(is_numeric($dados[$campo_unico])){

        }else {

        }
        $select->execute();

        if( ($select->rowCount()) > 0) {
            return "O ".$campo_unico." informado já existe em nossos registros";
        }else {
            insert2($dados, $tabela);
        }

    }
   //caso o código chegue aqui não existe nenhum return para satisfazer a assinatura do método.
}
```

Ao chamar `insert()` em caso de falha [`errorInfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) **retorna um array** ou seja será necessário um tratamento para converter ele em string, não basta apenas dar um `return insert2($dados, $tabela);` isso também viola a assinatura.

`insert2()` sofre do mesmo problema veja:

```
function insert2($dados, $tabela) : string{
 //código....

    if ($insert->execute()) {
        return "Registro inserido com sucesso";
    } else {
        return $insert->errorInfo(); //retorna um array o que quebra a assinatura
    }
 }
```

Para resolver o primeiro passo é retornar o tipo esperado, não retorne `errorInfo()` mas um

```
return implode(' - ', $insert->errorInfo());
```

**Relacionadas:**

[PHP 7 tem tipagem de argumentos e de retorno, mas é opcional. Isso é bom ou ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/91)

[Tipagem do retorno no PHP 7. Quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93707/91)

Comment: Deveria ser `return insert2($dados, $tabela)`

Comment: @PapaCharlie não :P editei a resposta (agora) com os detalhes.

Comment: Verdade, o array do `errorInfo` mata a tipagem. Se serializar a mensagem de erro teremos (string) sucesso, e (string) erro. [fuuu rs]. A função insert2 poderia remover a tipagem e jogar um `exception` pra função anterior tratar esse erro.

Comment: @PapaCharlie isso, se tem regra (tipagem do retorno) precisa seguir ela. Da pra usar um `implode()` e retornar o esperado ... exceptions usadas de maneira errada é pior ainda =\.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, resolvi o problema colocando os return conforme indicado, e para não violar a assinatura da função eu coloquei para retornar a posição do array errorInfo() que contem a mensagem de alerta: $error = $insert->errorInfo();
            return $error[2];

Answer (score 3):

*Se entendi o código*, creio que falta um return em:

```
if( ($select->rowCount()) > 0) {
    return "O ".$campo_unico." informado já existe em nossos registros";
}else {
    insert2($dados, $tabela);
}
```

Deveria ser:

```
if( ($select->rowCount()) > 0) {
    return "O ".$campo_unico." informado já existe em nossos registros";
}else {
    return insert2($dados, $tabela); //Faltava o return
}
```