# MVC + DAO - Qual forma deveria optar no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, padrão-dao

No Java, na classe de modelo eu posso criar na classe `funcionario` o atributo `Setor s`, porém o PHP não é tipado, como eu poderia resolver esse caso de associação?

Após algumas pesquisas aqui no site, vi que no PHP a classe Modelo do MVC é onde ficam métodos (CRUD...), porém no Java ficam apenas os atributos, e esses métodos na classe DAO, isso se deve ao uso da persistência de dados, ou apenas um jeito diferente de usar o MVC?

Comment: Tambem ainda tenho essa duvida

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> no Java, na classe Modelo eu posso criar na classe `funcionario` o atributo `Setor s`, porém o PHP não é tipado, como eu poderia resolver esse caso de associação?

A maneira como ensinaram OOP para as pessoas é baseado em linguagens estaticamente tipadas então há limitações quando tenta usar orientação a objeto em linguagens dinamicamente tipadas. Há uma forma de programação que é baseado no modelo do [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) que muitos chama de programação orientada a objeto, mas seu criador recentemente admite que o modelo é orientado à mensagens<sup>*</sup>.

PHP ainda é uma linguagem de *script*, seus códigos rodam por uma fração de segundo ou até por alguns segundos, então fazem coisas muito rápidas, são naturalmente microsserviços, então OO não é algo que ajude muito neste tipo de ambiente.

Por isso tentar reproduzir em PHP a forma como se faz em Java é esquisito, mesmo que seja o que todo mundo esteja fazendo. Não é algo com fundamento, é só porque alguém disse que quem não fizer assim é mulher do padre. Se deseja usar o mesmo modelo do Java e ter algo parecido com PHP use [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101), que é o que o PHP quer ser e é mantido por pessoas altamente qualificadas para fazer funcionar.

Nem Java chama isto que está se referindo como atributo, só em UML que o termo é usado oficialmente. [Nas linguagens isto chama-se campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). E em PHP não pode ter um tipo.

Um detalhe importante: muitas metodologias pregam que [não deve-se usar *getters/setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), eu acho exagero, mas faz algum sentido, na forma como as pessoas costumam usar está errado mesmo. Algumas perguntas para refletir:

- [Quando é útil separar estado de comportamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311349/101)
- [Por que não devo alterar os "getter"s e "setter"s?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101)
- [É realmente necessário usar métodos para mutator e acessor (setter e getter) no PHP? E o desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101)
- [Exemplo real do uso de encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293801/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre referenciar um atributo diretamente ou por get/set](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129353/101)

Uma das coisas que pode fazer em um *setter* em PHP é verificar se o dado é de determinado tipo. Mas [PHP já permite que coloque o tipo no parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116783/101) e o interpretador pode fazer a verificação para você. Isso faz mais sentido em uma linguagem compilada. Isto nem de perto é tipagem estática que Hack possui, é só [*type hinting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/101) que tem [alguma vantagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93707/101).

Aliás, classes na forma como é construída, para [usar como contrato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100489/101), só faz sentido em linguagem compilada e estaticamente tipada.

Uma forma que algumas pessoas usam e eu acho bem plausível, em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, apesar de eu ser filosoficamente contra é o uso de notação húngara. Assim todas variáveis, e até métodos poderiam ter no seu nome indicando qual é o tipo dela, o que é uma documentação difícil de ignorar, ainda que polua um pouco o nome. Mas novamente, se isto é uma preocupação, vai pra Hack, ou Java, ou outra linguagem que usa o melhor dos dois mundo, como C#.

Isso é uma rasa tentativa de evitar o [problema de Gettier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem) que impera por aí, o que não quer dizer que isto aqui seja o conhecimento que ele fala.

---

<sup>*</sup> OOP não é *message based*

- [Troca de e-mail com Alan Kay onde ele mostra implicitamente que o termo foi um infortúnio](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/%7Eram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en) (ele até diz que se opõe ao modelo que "todas" linguagem implementam OOP, por isso: ou parem de usar o termo OOP, ou parem de impor a visão dele para essas linguagens)
- [Mensagem de e-mail onde ele lamenta não ter focado em mensagens](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev/1998-October/017019.html)
- [Ele mesmo responde quando o questionam](http://qr.ae/TUI7o9)
- [Comentado](http://mythz.servicestack.net/blog/2013/02/27/the-deep-insights-of-alan-kay/)
- Entrada 2122503 da [ISO-IEC-2382-15](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:2382:ed-1:v1:en)
- Wikipedia sobre [passagem de mensagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing)
- [Discussão de gente altamente qualificada sobre o assunto](http://wiki.c2.com/?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented)
- Excelente [comparação entre os dois modelos de "OOP"](http://eed3si9n.com/oop)
- [Outra interessante reflexão](http://braythwayt.com/2013/12/22/wrong.html)
- Outra [comparação entre o modelo de Smalltalk e de C++](http://stereobooster.github.io/two-big-schools-of-object-oriented-programming)
- [Finalmente um debate interessante sobre o assunto](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3265)

[image: Tudo é objeto se comunicando através de mensagens X Abstração, herança e polimorfismo]

> caso eu quisesse o nome do setor em que o funcionário está relacionario, ficaria $f = new Funcionario(); $f->getSetor->getNome();

Respondendo comentário, não exatamente, seria mais algo como:

```
$f->getSetor()->getNome();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/NestedProperty.php).

Esta é uma forma de fazer, partindo do princípio que setor é um objeto que possui um método que pega o seu nome. Claro que poderia ignorar o *getter* e acessar direto o campo se torná-lo público.

> após algumas pesquisas aqui no site, vi que no PHP a classe Modelo do MVC é onde ficam métodos (crud...), porém no Java ficam apenas os atributos, e esses métodos na classe DAO, isso se deve ao uso da persistência de dados, ou apenas um jeito diferente de usar o MVC?

Existem várias formas de se ver o MVC. As classes (no plural) que representam um modelo costumam ter métodos que fazem todas operações que o objeto pode fazer, ou pode ter só os métodos que são regras de negócio (tem um DAO), ou podem ser completamente anêmicos e só possuírem estado, ou pode fazer um meio termo se fizer muito sentido.

As pessoas fazem de forma diferente por dois principais motivos:

- elas não sabem o que estão fazendo e só copiam um modelo que viram em algum lugar, portanto não importa, já é um erro a motivação do uso
- elas sabem o que estão fazendo e escolhem um caminho porque fazem mais sentido para eles trabalharem assim, seja porque a equipe trabalha desta forma, seja porque o problema que lida funciona melhor.

Há metodologias que pregam uma coisa ou outra. Não dá para dizer o que é mais certo, apesar seguir uma filosofia. Alguns *frameworks* obrigam fazer de uma determinada forma. Por exemplo: OOP mais puro usa a forma de ter tudo nele; DDD
já prega tudo muito separado, e há o meio termo que costuma ser mais pragmático.

Em ambientes muito organizados eu prefiro o DAO ou algo semelhante de forma separada. Em ambientes pouco organizados, o que não é o mesmo de bagunçado, apenas uma forma de pouca cerimônia, que é o que linguagens como PHP sempre pregou, aí você faz o que é mais simples e pode colocar junto se é algo específico. Pra falar a verdade uma das grandes vantagens que PHP tem e as pessoas estão jogando no lixo programando como se fosse Java é generalizar soluções e sequer precisar cuidar da gravação de forma específica.

Java não ajuda muito, embora possa fazer, mas mesmo linguagens mais burocráticas, como C# estão incentivando a generalização com reflexão e mais recentemente com geração de código, pode ter o melhor dos dois mundos.

As pessoas não fazem de forma diferente porque elas não entendem o que estão fazendo, só seguindo receitas de bolo encontradas em livros, ou pior, em blogs e vídeos na internet, ou pior ainda em *posts* isolados por em fóruns, outros sites e pasmem, em WhastsApp! Isso é o que se chama de "dica Miojo"<sup>*</sup>, é rápido, resolve seu problema em 3 minutos, mas depois te dá mais fome e te causa problema de saúde! E eu sei que ninguém vai ler tudo o que tem *linkado* para formar sua própria opinião :P

---

<sup>*</sup>Miojo é marca registrada da Nissin e não tem nada a ver com o assunto. O termo "Dica Miojo" é invenção do meu amigo [João **Benito** "Excel man" Savastano](https://www.linkedin.com/in/joaobenito/).

Comment: Valeu, isso me tirou bastante dúvida em relação a essa parte do DAO, e é realmente como você disse "As pessoas não fazem de forma diferente porque elas não entendem o que estão fazendo", esse é/era meu caso em relação a isso.

Comment: Sim, @Leandro normal quando está aprendendo, não deveria ser normal quando é experiente :)

Comment: Útil: [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21508/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1tica-e-din%C3%A2mica)

Answer (score 1):

> Primeira dúvida: no Java, na classe Modelo eu posso criar na Classe funcionario o atributo Setor s, porém o PHP não é tipado, como eu poderia resolver esse caso de associação?

Você cria o atributo do mesmo jeito:

```
class Funcionario{
    private $setor;
    //...getters e setters
}
```

Obviamente, nada vai te obrigar a colocar em *setor* um objeto do tipo Setor, mas se você for minimamente organizado vai saber que essa variável foi criada pra isso. Outra opção é usar algum tipo de validação nos setters, se garantir o tipo for tão crítico pra você.

> Segunda dúvida: após algumas pesquisas aqui no site, vi que no PHP a
>   classe Modelo do MVC é onde ficam métodos (crud...), porém no Java
>   ficam apenas os atributos, e esses métodos na classe DAO, isso se deve
>   ao uso da persistência de dados, ou apenas um jeito diferente de usar
>   o MVC?

Isso é mais organização de quem está escrevendo o código do que regra geral. Por definição no Model é onde ficariam as regras de negócio da aplicação, mas como muitas vezes o que vemos na internet são exemplos mais simples e didáticos, você vê esse tipo de coisa. Outra questão é que a maioria dos frameworks PHP não usam DAO para a persistência, mas o modelo de ActiveRecord, onde a própria classe da entidade persistente contém os métodos de CRUD. Isso acaba criando essas situações onde sistemas simples acabam criando Models que apenas repassam o CRUD, ao invés de terem realmente alguma lógica de negócio.

Comment: Só uma dúvida em relação a primeira resposta, caso eu quisesse o nome do setor em que o funcionário está relacionario, ficaria $f = new Funcionario(); $f->getSetor->getNome(); ?