# Como o PHP lida com a declaração de tipos?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Ainda no PHP 5 já era possível fazer a declaração de [tipos em argumentos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) da função.

> #### Declarações de tipo
>
> Declarações de tipo permitem que funções requiram que parâmetros sejam
>   de certos tipos ao chamá-los. Se o valor informado no parâmetro tiver
>   um tipo incorreto então um erro é gerado: no PHP 5 será um erro fatal
>   recuperável, enquanto que no PHP 7 irá lançar uma exceção TypeError
>
> Para declarar o tipo o seu nome deve ser adicionado antes no nome do
>   parâmetro. A declaração pode ser feita para aceitar NULL se o valor
>   default do parâmetro for configurado também para NULL.

A partir do PHP 7 é possível declarar o [tipo de retorno](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) de uma determinada função.

> #### Declaração de tipo de retorno
>
> O PHP 7 acrescenta suporte a declaração de tipo de retorno. Similar à
>   declaração de tipagem de argumentos, declaração de tipo de retorno
>   especifica o tipo do valor que será retornado de uma função. Os mesmos
>   tipos que estão disponíveis para declaração de argumentos estão
>   disponíveis para tipagem de retornos.
>
> A tipagem estrita também afeta a tipagem de retorno. No modo padrão
>   (tripagem fraca) o valores retornados serão convertidos para o tipo
>   correto caso não enquadrem no tipo informado. No modo de tipagem forte
>   os valores retornados precisam ser o tipo correto ou uma exceção
>   TypeError será lançada.

Porém, na documentação, nada é dito sobre a necessidade de o tipo estar declarado ou não no escopo atual. Fiz o teste e percebi que o PHP não faz a verificação se o tipo está declarado e continua tento o mesmo comportamento supracitado.

```
function foo(): Foo {
    return 'foo';
}

foo();
```

A saída será a exceção `TypeError`:

```
Return value of foo() must be an instance of Foo, string returned
```

Como, então, a linguagem verifica se o retorno é uma instância de `Foo` sem que a classe `Foo` exista? Avaliando o comportamento a estrutura `instanceof` podemos perceber que ela aceita a verificação a partir de apenas o nome da classe, como *string*.

```
$obj = 'foo';
$class = 'Foo';

var_dump($obj instanceof $class);  // bool(false)
```

É esse o comportamento utilizado na verificação de tipos de argumentos e retornos? O interpretador armazena internamente o tipo como *string* e faz a verificação apenas a partir do nome?

Comment: Muito boa a pergunta, também gostaria de saber isso com mais detalhes.

Comment: É uma questão bem interessante. Será que publicando a questão em https://bugs.php.net/report.php poderiam dar uma avaliação mais aprofundada do caso?

Comment: Anderson, me parece que a avaliação está equivocada. O seu `var_dump` demonstra que `$obj` não é instância de Foo. Da mesma maneira, o `TypeError` lançado está correto, uma vez que a validação inicial (string !== (instance of Foo)) ocorre, não é necessário que o interpretador verifique se a classe Foo existe ou não. O erro de existência da classe ocorerria se o retorno for `return new Foo`.

Comment: @RafaelAraújo Mas é exatamente essa a pergunta, sobre como o PHP analisa o tipo de retorno mesmo quando o tipo não está definido. Não entendi qual seria a avaliação equivocada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a primeira verificação é `retornoDaFuncao === retornoDefinidoDaFuncao`. Esta verificação é feita via metada do nome do tipo de dado e por isso não é necessário que o tipo de dado efetivamente exista.

Comment: @RafaelAraújo Essa não seria a resposta? Qual é a avaliação equivocada que diz que fiz na pergunta? O `var_dump` no final foi para mostrar que o `instaceof` funciona com *strings* e não precisa existir o tipo para fazer essa verificação. Logo depois disso perguntei se é assim que o interpretador faz internamente, se ele armazena o tipo de retorno como *string* para fazer a verificação posteriormente. Se souber como isso funciona internamente, por favor elabore uma resposta :D

Comment: Beleza. Vou lançar como resposta. ;-)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93707/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procurando no [código fonte do PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src), mais especificamente no arquivo [`Zend/zend_execute.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute.c), existe uma função [`zend_verify_internal_return_type`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1244), que verifica qual é o retorno de uma função do PHP, e, dentro dela, é chamada a função [`zend_check_type`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1049), que checa o valor retornado com o tipo da função, a parte relevante para a questão é:

```
if (ZEND_TYPE_IS_CLASS(type)) {
    if (EXPECTED(*cache_slot)) {
        *ce = (zend_class_entry *) *cache_slot;
    } else {
        *ce = zend_fetch_class(ZEND_TYPE_NAME(type), (ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_AUTO | ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_NO_AUTOLOAD));
        if (UNEXPECTED(!*ce)) {
            return Z_TYPE_P(arg) == IS_NULL && (ZEND_TYPE_ALLOW_NULL(type) || (default_value && is_null_constant(scope, default_value)));
        }
        *cache_slot = (void *) *ce;
    }
    if (EXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(arg) == IS_OBJECT)) {
        return instanceof_function(Z_OBJCE_P(arg), *ce);
    }
    return Z_TYPE_P(arg) == IS_NULL && (ZEND_TYPE_ALLOW_NULL(type) || (default_value && is_null_constant(scope, default_value)));
} else if [ ... ]
```

Observação: o valor da variável `default_value` sempre será nulo, ele é usado apenas na verificação do tipo dos parâmetros da função, então a expressão entre parênteses depois do OU lógico sempre será falsa. Assim como o `cache_slot` também sempre será nulo e o conteúdo dentro da condição `EXPECTED(*cache_slot)` nunca será executado. Ambas as variáveis sempre são nulas porque dentro da função `zend_verify_internal_return_type` é chamado `zend_check_type` passando sempre `NULL`:

```
static int zend_verify_internal_return_type(zend_function *zf, zval *ret)
{
    zend_internal_arg_info *ret_info = zf->internal_function.arg_info - 1;
    zend_class_entry *ce = NULL;
    void *dummy_cache_slot = NULL;

    if (ZEND_TYPE_CODE(ret_info->type) == IS_VOID) {
        if (UNEXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(ret) != IS_NULL)) {
            zend_verify_void_return_error(zf, zend_zval_type_name(ret), "");
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    if (UNEXPECTED(!zend_check_type(ret_info->type, ret, &ce, &dummy_cache_slot, NULL, NULL, 1, 0))) {
        zend_verify_internal_return_error(zf, ce, ret);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Observe que nessa função já é verificado se o tipo é `void` e o retorno é `NULL`

Se o tipo da função for uma classe, então ele procura a classe, como a classe não existe, será executado a linha:

```
return Z_TYPE_P(arg) == IS_NULL && (ZEND_TYPE_ALLOW_NULL(type) || (default_value && is_null_constant(scope, default_value)));
```

Que verificará se o tipo do retorno é NULL e se a função aceita o retorno nulo, não é o seu caso, então essa função retornará falso

Agora, se a classe for encontrada e o tipo do retorno for um objeto, então é usado a função [`instanceof_function`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2327) para verificar se o retorno é uma instância da classe encontrada

Então, mesmo que crie uma função e a mesma retornar um objeto qualquer, o PHP nunca vai lançar uma exceção devido ao tipo não ter sido declarado ainda, em vez disso ele lançará uma exceção do tipo `TypeError`:

```
function foo(): Foo {
  return new DateTime();
}

foo();
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of foo() must be an instance of Foo, instance of DateTime returned in [...]

Mesmo que o tipo definido não existir, mas a função poder retornar `NULL` (prefixando o tipo com uma interrogação `?`) e realmente retornar `NULL`, o código será executado com sucesso:

```
function bar(): ?Bar {
  return null;
}

bar();
```

Permitindo algo como:

```
function baz(arrray $args): ?Baz {
  return class_exists('Baz') ? new Baz(...$args) : null;
};

baz($args);
```

Que verifica se a classe existe e, se sim, retorna sua instância, se não, retorna nulo

Answer (score 1):

Oi, Anderson.

Sim, neste passo de compatibilização da assinatura com o retorno, a linguagem verifica se o retorno é uma instância de Foo sem que a classe Foo exista.

Considerando o momento a partir de que estamos no momento do retorno da função, ou seja, já passamos com sucesso tanto a execução da entrada da função quanto do corpo da função com sucesso, e estamos no passo em que a função está retornando o resultado de sua execução:

No retorno, o interpretador vai consultar o metadado da definição do tipo de dado que está sendo retornado. Em seu exemplo, o metadado do que será retornado é do tipo `string`, um tipo interno, e ele será comparado com o metadado da assinatura do método, que está definido como `Foo`, um objeto. Estas estruturas são comparadas e, por serem incompatíveis, o interpretador já lança o erro de tipo.

Já que de qualquer maneira há uma incompatibilidade, este passo é realizado sem a necessidade de verificação da existência da representação de `Foo` no sistema a fim de economizar recursos, pois, se compatíveis (ambos são objetos, por exemplo), aí sim o interpretador teria que comparar os objetos em toda a complexidade da cadeira (herança, implementação de interfaces, etc).

Comment: Mas como é feita essa comparação? Consegue demonstrar com alguma fonte oficial (documentação/código) de como isso acontece? Pois abri a pergunta justamente porque não fica claro como é esse processo internamente.