# O que são tipos no retorno de um método?

Tags: java, tipagem, return

Utilizei o PHP e nunca vi isso, sabemos que existe os tipos de retorno `double`, `float`, `int`, `boolean`.

No Java quando queremos retornar um `int` fazemos assim:

```
public int soma(int numero1,int numero2) {
return numero1+numero2;

}
```

Agora o que eu não estou entendendo é que recentemente vi algo novo nesses tipos de retorno. Estou vendo códigos que retorna variável do tipo `Connection` do tipo. O que significa isso?:

```
public static Connection obterConexao() {
     Connection conn = null;
   try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/banco","root","senha");
   }catch(SQLException e) {
       System.out.println("erro ao conectar");
   }
   return conn;
}
```

Vai retornar `string`, `int`, `double`? Como funciona isso?

Também esse `static` que não vi no PHP.

Não é só nisso, já vi vários códigos usando retornos sem ser
`int`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, eles estão usando nome de variável como assim isso? Como usar isso? Pra que serve?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Nos pontos que você mencionou, não existe diferença entre PHP e Java. Em ambas as linguagens é possível a criação de novos tipos pelo programador, e esses tipos podem, naturalmente, constituir valor de retorno de um método ou função. No seu caso, a função `obterConexao` retorna uma objeto do tipo Connection (ou uma instância da classe Connection). Quanto a `static`, PHP também permite a criação de métodos estáticos, isto é, que pertencem a classe e não a uma instância específica.

Comment: Obrigado vander

Comment: @edenilson poderia explicar seu edit? Me parece que a postagem foi vandalizada, e isto não é permitido aqui. Estou aguardando uns instantes antes de efetuar o procedimento nesses casos, caso tenha sido só um engano.

Comment: pode excluir , depois de umas respostas que eu recebi,

Comment: O procedimento não é exclusão, e sim reversão e aviso para não fazer novamente. Uma vez postado, o conteúdo faz parte do esforço coletivo da comunidade. Mais detalhes em [help] e nos termos que aceitou ao criar a conta. Sobre as respostas, a votação classifica conforme a comunidade entender útil (mais detalhes no [tour]).

Comment: blz ta tudo certo

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta é confusa e mostra que está aprendendo sem uma estrutura. Isso não dá certo, aprende tudo pela metade, coisas erradas, pula etapas. É como construir uma casa sem alicerce, faltando tijolos. Não aconselho fazer isso. Aprendeu alguns itens, agora aprenderá outro que faltou, mas continuará faltando outros. Falta estrutura até no texto, em código é necessário mais estrutura ainda.

[Isso é exatamente um tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324630/101), nada mais que isso. Se aprendeu que tipo é uma lista de meia dúzia de nomes, aprendeu errado. Um tipo é o que define como um dado deve ser ou se comportar. A linguagem tem alguns próprios, a biblioteca da linguagem tem outros, bibliotecas de terceiros também tem, e sua aplicação criará vários outros.

[Em PHP também é assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/101), embora de forma um pouco mais limitada. [Em PHP 7 e 8 nem é tão limitado assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93707/101) (apesar de ser uma gambiarra da linguagem), então não é algo de Java, é de programação em geral ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438511/101)).

Não temos como saber o que é o tipo `Connection` porque podem ter vários tipos com esse nome em contextos diferentes. A biblioteca padrão tem uma interface com esse nome, que não deixa de ser um tipo. Olhando a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), que deve fazer sempre, pode ver mais sobre isso.

Mas pode não entender o que é [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101), como funciona a `Connection`. Mas aí é porque pulou etapas demais. Tem que começar com coisas mais simples. Não dá para escrever um livro de programação inteiro aqui para falar de tudo o que está faltando saber.

Se pegar exemplos ruins vai aprender errado. Esse parece um que faz errado (muito comum), mas não tenho informação suficiente para afirmar. Hoje na internet é um lugar ruim para se aprender, porque um faz errado, se torna popular, e todo mundo copia o errado fazendo parecer que está certo. Isso tem destruído a capacidade das pessoas aprenderem certo. Quem está começando não é capaz de separar conteúdo bom de ruim. Um emite uma opinião, você gosta e acha que aquilo é verdade.

O `static` também tem em PHP, o fato de não ter visto é só que não aprendeu PHP bem o suficiente. E começa ter perguntas demais na mesma postagem. [Eu respondi muito sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20static%20%5Bjava%5D), outras pessoas também (mas nem todos organizam para ser fácil de achar). Pesquise no site que quase tudo o que quiser já foi perguntado antes. Ainda não é a melhor forma de aprender, mas ajuda. Ainda deve procurar um livro de qualidade, moderno.

Pode pesquisar sobre as [perguntas mais populares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes). Pode ir [só nas de Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), mas perderá muitos conceitos importantes como exemplo: [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101) e [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

Por fim: [Como uma máquina identifica o tipo de dado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158605/101). Mas tem outros sobre tipagem. Só reforço para aprender primeiros os conceitos, os fundamentos, os mecanismos mais básicos, só para depois ir para coisas mais sofisticadas. Você não aprende equação do segundo grau quando não sabe aritmética. O problema é a metodologia de aprendizado.